# Not able to use UART on MSP430F5529LP

Tags: c, embedded, uart, communication, msp430

I have my MSP on Com8. Here is my code:

```
#include <msp430.h>
void Uart_SendChar(char c);
int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;

    P4SEL |= BIT4+BIT5;                       // P3.3,4 = USCI_A0 TXD/RXD
    UCA1CTL1 |= UCSWRST;                      // **Put state machine in reset**
    UCA1CTL1 |= UCSSEL_2;                     // SMCLK
    UCA1BR0 = 9;                              // 1MHz 115200
    UCA1BR1 = 0;                              // 1MHz 115200
    UCA1MCTL |= UCBRS_1 + UCBRF_0;            // Modulation UCBRSx=1, UCBRFx=0
    UCA1CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;

    while(1)
    {
        Uart_SendChar('k');
        __delay_cycles(3000000); //3sn Bekleme suresi
    }
}

void Uart_SendChar(char c)
{
    UCA1TXBUF=c;
    while(UCA1STAT&UCBUSY);
}
```

But I'm not getting any output. What might be the reason why?

Comment: You would need a scope or logic analyzer to see if there is a signal on the lines.

Comment: Always get the TI example to run first. There should be a UART example.

Comment: This is based on the TI example, and there are no obvious errors. It's likely that you are using the wrong COM port, or have not configured it correctly, but you have told us nothing about that.

Comment: Check if the port supports 115200. I have add issues with MSP430F5529LP UART ports. Try to run at 9600.

Comment: @CL. it shows at com 8 , so that is what I selected, and the baud rate is 11520 as mentioned in the comments

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena tried , didnt work

Comment: The most classic mistakes is connecting tx and rx wrong, or forgetting signal ground. Which is some of the numerous reasons why you absolutely need an oscilloscope in order to develop any embedded system.

Comment: Are you trying to read from Port 3, Pin 3,4 or Port 3 Pin 4,5? Are you using a USB to Serial Cable or using the Virtual com port. Port configuration look OK as suggest by others. Below is some old code I found. I confirmed that this is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the following code to check if your system is working properly.

```
//******************************************************************************
//   MSP430F552x Demo - USCI_A0, 115200 UART Echo ISR, DCO SMCLK
//
//   Description: Echo a received character, RX ISR used. Normal mode is LPM0.
//   USCI_A0 RX interrupt triggers TX Echo.
//   Baud rate divider with 1048576hz = 1048576/115200 = ~9.1 (009h|01h)
//   ACLK = REFO = ~32768Hz, MCLK = SMCLK = default DCO = 32 x ACLK = 1048576Hz
//
//                 MSP430F552x
//             -----------------
//         /|\|                 |
//          | |                 |
//          --|RST              |
//            |                 |
//            |     P3.3/UCA0TXD|------------>
//            |                 | 115200 - 8N1
//            |     P3.4/UCA0RXD|<------------
//
//******************************************************************************

#include <msp430.h>

int main(void)
{
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;                 // Stop WDT

  P3SEL |= BIT3+BIT4;                       // P3.3,4 = USCI_A0 TXD/RXD
  UCA0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;                      // **Put state machine in reset**
  UCA0CTL1 |= UCSSEL_2;                     // SMCLK
  UCA0BR0 = 9;                              // 1MHz 115200 (see User's Guide)
  UCA0BR1 = 0;                              // 1MHz 115200
  UCA0MCTL |= UCBRS_1 + UCBRF_0;            // Modulation UCBRSx=1, UCBRFx=0
  UCA0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;                     // **Initialize USCI state machine**
  UCA0IE |= UCRXIE;                         // Enable USCI_A0 RX interrupt

  __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE);       // Enter LPM0, interrupts enabled
  __no_operation();                         // For debugger
}

// Echo back RXed character, confirm TX buffer is ready first
#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector=USCI_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCI_A0_ISR(void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(USCI_A0_VECTOR))) USCI_A0_ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
{
  switch(__even_in_range(UCA0IV,4))
  {
  case 0:break;                             // Vector 0 - no interrupt
  case 2:                                   // Vector 2 - RXIFG
    while (!(UCA0IFG&UCTXIFG));             // USCI_A0 TX buffer ready?
    UCA0TXBUF = UCA0RXBUF;                  // TX -> RXed character
    break;
  case 4:break;                             // Vector 4 - TXIFG
  default: break;
  }
}
```

Below is output from Tera Term

[image]

For this demo I am using Port 3 Pin 3, 4, which in on J1 Connector. I used a USB to serial cable.

[image]

Below are some links that should help you get start learning how work on MSP430F5529LP. In some cases you might need to setup account on my.ti.com before you can download the material.

**References:**

- [MSP-EXP430F5529LP  1_05_00_03](https://software-dl.ti.com/msp430/msp430_public_sw/mcu/msp430/MSP-EXP430F5529LP/latest/index_FDS.html)
- [MSP430 Design Workshop](https://software-dl.ti.com/trainingTTO/trainingTTO_public_sw/MSP_Design_Workshop/MSP_Design_Workshop.pdf)
- [MSP430f5529 UART over USB to realterm on PC](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/msp-low-power-microcontroller-forum/400317/msp430f5529-uart-over-usb-to-realterm-on-pc)
- [MSP430F5529: How to test the UART example MSP430F55xx_uscia0_uart_01.c](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/msp-low-power-microcontroller-forum/651900/msp430f5529-how-to-test-the-uart-example-msp430f55xx_uscia0_uart_01-c)

Comment: bruh, thanks, I will try it out  and revert asap

Comment: much thanks, it works, I had a faulty usb.

Comment: @RasenRhino, Thank you

Comment: Glad was able to make a simple contribution to your learning journey.